# Should I remove any listeners when activity is destroyed/paused? Android Studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I wondered if I should explicitly remove any **observers/listeners** when the application goes to background/destroyed.
or should'nt I remove becuase the android machine knows when to remove?

***thanks :)***

Comment: Well there is UI event listeners which you do not have to remove because there will be no action when app is not in foreground.  Rest all depends upon your use case most of the time you have to remove the listeners. for exa-. if you are getting location updates in an activity then you need to remove it when destroyed

Comment: The observers related to the UI will be automatically removed  but the ones related to background tasks should be removed only if the activity is destroyed, not when in the background or paused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you mean UI listeners like `onClickListener` for a button then now that's ok because when the app is in the background no action could be taken. and when activity is destroyed all the listeners will be destroyed too.

but if your activity is ***observing*** another class and updates itself according to changes in that class then *you need to register activity in `onStart` and unregister in `onStop()` of the activity*. otherwise, it could cause exceptions since the activity is not active.

another case you should watch out for is when you create a `Thread` inside your activity, which is a static inner class and has a reference to your activity. and as long as the Thread is running the activity won't get garbage collected. this could lead to memory leaks if activity dies before the thread is done like